# html5 video.js block pointer events in progress bar - greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey, video.js

I want to lock the slider while watching a movie.
Children sometimes click while watching and I have to look for where they stopped watching the fairy tale.

Sample short video here: http://phturek.domenomania.eu/gus/v.php

I read about Tampermonkey and Greasemonkey but despite a few attempts and checking various scripts, I could not solve the problem.

At the moment, when I turn on the fairy tale, I do it manually in firefox - SHIFT + F7 and type it

`.vjs-progress-control {pointer-events: none! important; }`

I would like this to be permanently set in Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This was done using the Stylus plugin for the browser. The question can be ended.